# How many bit strings containing exactly eleven 0s and nine 1s have either all the 0s consecutive, or have all the 1s consecutive?

Tags: combinatorics

How many bit strings containing exactly eleven 0s and nine 1s have either all the 0s consecutive, or have all
the 1s consecutive?

Comment: Have you tried writing out some examples for smaller numbers?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?

Answer (score 2):

From your question the bit strings in question are of length 20.
Number of bit strings with all its 11 0s consecutive = number of positions available for the first 0 in this block of 11 consecutive 0s = 10.
So the number of bit strings with all its 11 0s consecutive is 10.
Now number of bit strings with all its 9 1s consecutive = 12
(By the same argument as above).
Finally, the number of bit strings in which both its 11 0s and  9 1s are consecutive = 2 ( First a block of 9 1s followed by 11 0s or vice versa).
By the Principle of inclusion exclusion,
Number of bit strings with either 0s or 1s consecutive = 12+10-2=20

Comment: Your answer is incorrect.  Notice that the string with nine $1$s followed by $11$ $0$s satisfies the requirements.  However, the first $0$ is in the tenth position.  You made the same mistake for strings with $9$ consecutive $1$s.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Am sorry and thanks for pointing it out. I've corrected it. Can you pls tell if the ans is correct now or is there any other logic flaw?

Comment: It is correct now.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you so much!